# Why does this error come up when creating an Invoice via BLC code?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create an Invoice in the Invoice and Memo / ARInvoiceEntry Graph using BLC code.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
ARInvoiceEntry arinventry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARInvoiceEntry>();
ARInvoice arinvoice = new ARInvoice();

arinvoice.DocType = "Invoice";
arinvoice.DocDate = DateTime.Now;

//Get the customer ID...
var cust = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.acctCD, Equal<Required<Customer.acctCD>>>>.Select(Base, CustomerCode); //"ABARTENDE");
if (cust != null)
     arinvoice.CustomerID = cust.BAccountID;

//Get the project ID...
var proj = (PMProject)PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProject.contractCD, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractCD>>>>.Select(Base, JobNbr);
if (proj != null)
     arinvoice.ProjectID = proj.ContractID;

//Insert the record...
arinventry.Document.Insert(arinvoice);
arinventry.Persist()
```

Every time I try this, I get the following error:

[image]

This does not happen when I enter the exact same data manually - the numbering sequence is set up correctly - this has been verified.  The trace tells me nothing of any value, but here it is:

```
3/14/2023 2:36:41 PM Error:
CS Error: Cannot generate the next number for the  sequence.
at PX.Objects.CS.AutoNumberAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
at PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoiceEntry.Persist()
at HELInvoicesAndMemos.ARInvoiceEntryExt.GetInvoiceRecordsToIntegrate() in D:\Acumatica     Customization projects\HELInvoicesAndMemos 22.112.0018\ARInvoiceEntryExt.cs:line 185
at HELInvoicesAndMemos.ARInvoiceEntryExt.b__4_0() in D:\Acumatica Customization projects\HELInvoicesAndMemos 22.112.0018\ARInvoiceEntryExt.cs:line 38
at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0()
```

Am I missing something?  I've done this kind of BLC code many times in the past with no problems.

Comment: Try to set the Invoice Type, insert the record and then apply all the other values and do Update(arinvoice). This error may be caused by the fact that the numbering is applied when the Invoice Type is selected.

Comment: Nah - tried that.  Same error.  Thanks, though...

Comment: how is your numbering configured? May it be so that you have branch specific number and are missing that specific branch?

Comment: Actually, Just to eliminate any site-specific issues, I created a fresh instance for the same build with no other customizations and the SalesDemo data - and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
arinvoice.DocType = "INV";
```

or better yet

```
arinvoice.DocType = ARInvoiceType.Invoice;
```

Comment: That did it.  Jeez - how stupid can I be.  Sorry for wasting your time - but thanks... ;D

Comment: hehe fresh eyes :)